# Can't find controller in routes file hapijs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

i'm fairly new to the whole Nodejs world and I'm trying to create a simple app with Hapi.js to get myself started around here. Anyways, I've got my routes file setup this way:

```
var usersController = require("./src/controllers/usersController.js");
exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
    server.route([  
        {
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/register',
            handler: usersController.register
        }, 
    ]);
    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'routes',
    version: '0.0.1'
};
```

and then I have my controller

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var UserModel = require('./src/models/user.js');


function UsersController(){};
UsersController.prototype = (function(){

return {
    register: function register(request, reply) {
        var newUser = User({
          name: request.params.name,
          username: request.params.username,
          password: request.params.password
        });

        newUser.save(function(err){
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log("You created a user, bruh"); 
        })

    },
}
})();

var usersController = new UsersController();
module.exports = usersController;
```

the error i'm getting from the console is "Cannot find module ./src/controllers/usersController.js". I even tried to type up the absolute location of the file inside the require and got the same error, so I must be failing somewhere else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths are relative to the files, not to the project root. So for example in your controller you should use `'../models/user.js'`:

```
var UserModel = require('../models/user.js');
```